# Configure apache to respond with error page for incorrect hosts

Tags: django, apache

django docs:

> You should also configure the Web server that sits in front of Django to validate the host. It should respond with a static error page or ignore requests for incorrect hosts instead of forwarding the request to Django. This way you’ll avoid spurious errors in your Django logs (or emails if you have error reporting configured that way). For example, on nginx you might setup a default server to return “444 No Response” on an unrecognized host:

I am using Apache and this works:
http://serverip -> 404 error
http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com -> django site
http://example.com -> https://example.com -> django site

Now I have a problem with https://serverip
I get a not secure message by my browser because I only have a SSL Cert for example.com, www.example.com and after I accept the security warning I see the django site but I want 404 error page.
How can I achieve this or do I misunderstand the django docs?

**Update Config:**
assume the django site is /var/www/html/index.html for simplification
000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
```

example.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin example@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

example.com-le-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin example@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: do you want to show page 404 ?

Comment: yes for https://serverip because of the django doc

Comment: create one template called '404.html' and place it in where index.html file resides on apache

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I updated my post with my settings for VirtualHost. assume the django site is /var/www/html/index.html for simplification

Comment: another way is that you can place  '404.html' template in your project folders template where index.html file and make django Debug=false so it will automatically called to 404.html if url doesnt exist.

Comment: I want that my webserver response with 404 when the host is different from www.example.com / example.com. It works for http but not for https. So I think I have to add something to my virtualhost configuration.

Comment: why not add a <VirtualHost *:443>Redirect 404 /</VirtualHost> default config like for port 80?

Comment: I had this but than I get an error for example.com, www.example.com, https://serverip "Secure Connection Failed An error occurred during a connection to www.example.com. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG". Only http://serverip works and response with 404